# Why does s3.amazonaws.com respond with 400 Bad Request when I connect over telnet?

Tags: http, telnet, amazon-s3, network-protocols

This is what my request looks like. I have confirmed that the end of line separator is CRLF:

```
telnet s3.amazonaws.com 80

GET / HTTP/1.1
Host: s3.amazonaws.com
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:83.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/83.0
Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.5
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Connection: close
Cache-Control: max-age=0
```

I have tested on other sites and they work so it's something about this site that's the issue. I am using the telnet client that comes with Windows.

Comment: For whatever it's worth, I got a 307 Temporary Redirect when I tried your request. Attempted in a Ubuntu WSL2 terminal.

Comment: Thanks for trying. I also tried it on telnet on Centos 7.3 and I'm still getting a Bad Request response.